# Problem syncing iPhone contacts to outlook

Tags: iphone, microsoft-outlook-2003

A friend of mine syncs her iPhone with outlook. When she adds a appointment in outlook or on the iPhone, it syncs immediately without problems.
When adding or changing a contact in outlook it syncs to the iPhone perfectly.

But when she adds or changes a contact on the iPhone the changes will not sync to outlook.

Any ideas what might be wrong and how I can help her to fix it?

Comment: How is the syncing done, using MS Exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that when she creates a contact, it is created in the folder that the iPhone is syncing with Outlook.

Take a look at `Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendar > Contacts > Default Account` and make sure the contacts are created in the account that is set to be synced.

Comment: Ah, good point - what about changing contacts on the iPhone, would that be affected, too?

Comment: Contacts changed on the iPhone should also be changed in Outlook if they are both set to use the same account.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thanks! Now I need to figure out which contacts on the iPhone had been added with the wrong default account, and how to move them to the right one :(